# Distribution of Poisson random variable modulo $m$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation, poisson-distribution

Let $N$ be a Poisson random variable with rate $\lambda >0$. Set $X:=N\pmod m$. What is the pmf and expectation of $X$?

For $j=0,1,\dotsc,m-1$, we have $\{X=j\}=\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty \{N=j+mk\},$
so 
$$P(X=j)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(N=j+mk)=e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{j+mk}}{(j+mk)!},$$
which converges but I can't find its sum. For $\lambda^m<1$, the estimates, 
$$P(X=j)\leq \frac{1}{1-\lambda^m} P(N=j)$$
and
$$\mathbb{E}(X)\leq \frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda^m},$$
hold. These were derived by considering the geometric series for $1/(1-\lambda^m)$ and comparing the two... but this doesn't help with the original  problem...

Is there anyway to continue or an alternate route of attack? Resources for studying discrete random variables modulo $m$ in general?

Comment: Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ and set $\omega := e^{2\pi i/k}$.  Then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{kn} x^{kn} = \frac{1}{k} (f(x) + f(\omega x) + f(\omega^2 x) + \cdots + f(\omega^{k-1} x))$.  Not sure if that actually gives a useful answer in general for this case, though, where $f(x) = e^{-\lambda} e^{\lambda x}$.

Comment: Thanks. This yields $P(X=0)=\frac{1}{m}(1+e^{\lambda(\omega-1)}+\dotso+e^{\lambda(\omega^{m-1}-1)})$, where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/m}$ but I don't see it being applicable to calculating $P(X=j)$ .

Comment: Well, more generally, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{kn+\ell} x^{kn+\ell} = \frac{1}{k} (f(x) + \omega^{-\ell} f(\omega x) + \cdots + \omega^{-\ell(k-1)} f(\omega^{k-1} x))$ for $0 \le \ell < n$.